# Bash exits after successfully running docker-compose

Tags: bash, ssh, docker-compose

I can ssh onto a machine and run the following script

```
echo testing
docker-compose exec -T meteor php artisan down
echo done
```

which returns

```
testing
Application is now in maintenance mode.
done
```

However it I try and run that command over ssh it exits immediately after the docker-compose call.

```
ssh me@me.com << EOF
    echo testing
    docker-compose exec -T meteor php artisan down
    echo done
EOF
```

gives

```
testing
Application is now in maintenance mode.
```

ie `done` is missing

I can get it to continue by adding `&&` after the docker-compose command but i've got a long script and it makes it ugly and error prone if I have to explicity state this.

Any idea why this is happening and what I can change to fix it.

---

Update

I removed the `-T` from docker-compose and the script ran to completion however it gave the message `the input device is not a TTY`. It appears it can't allocate the interactive console. After a bit more googling I found that I can call

```
export COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1
```

And then it will run to completion without giving error messages.

Thanks all for the help :)

Comment: What exit code is `docker-compose` returning?

Comment: It exits before I can print the code. Ah, actually if I use && echo $? i get it. 130. Which seems to be that a ctrl + c was sent ... but not by me.... Any way I can reset this?

Comment: seems odd to me that `&& echo $?` executes for a nonzero code, but perhaps the environment is exiting because of what it sees as a failure. Personally, I would throw the whole thing into a script with error checking and logging &c, but if it isn't worth all that to you and you just want to plow ahead, add a `||:` on the end of the `docker-compose` command to tell it to just shut up and keep going.

Comment: Your script inherits *its* standard input from `ssh`, so it's possible that `docker-compose` is reading from its standard input, which means it would read the `echo done` line before the remote shell that ran `docker-compose` gets the chance.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was being caused by the -T flag to docker-compose.

This was added because an error message was being printed if it wasn't there. `the input device is not a TTY`

I found you could prevent docker-compose from creating an interactive terminal if you use

```
export COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1
```

Then the script runs correctly without the -T option.